# Getting warning after importing plugin to unity5 project

Tags: unity

I am getting following warning when I import any plugin to my unity5 project.Whats the solution for this warning? Is there any problem with that which will affect my project.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that warning is because the scripting API has changed slightly in Unity 5. Clearly (and unsurprisingly, since Unity 5 was just released) the code in this plugin was written using commands from Unity 4 that were changed.

When you click "I made a backup, go ahead" the scripts will be automatically updated, replacing all the Unity 4 functions with their equivalent in Unity 5. This update will actually change the code, which is why it says to make a backup first (in case the changes break something in your project).

In the long run, the plugin author should update their code to work in Unity 5, but obviously that is a consideration for *them* not *you*.

Comment: To add onto this, I've found the automatic update does a very good job. I've encountered this on two or three different projects, and (knock on wood), updating hasn't broken my code yet. So, do still make a backup, but don't be too worried if you see this message. Letting it update the code for you should be pretty painless. :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is having a backup and clicking the button "I made a backup, go ahead".

You are hopefully already under version control (are you?), so backup shouldn't be an issue.